# get count after using groupingBy condition on multiple fileds

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I want to get counts of userId after using groupingBy condition on multiple fields

my model class.

```
public class ModelClass{
int bussAssId;
int trackingId;
int userId;
int month;
String day;
int hour;
String deviceType ;

//Setter and Getters
}
```

in service class using JpaRepositroy I am getting List of Data. Here usedId can be same but trackingId will be unique.

```
List<ModelClass> sqlModelList=postgreSQLRepository.findByBussAssId(bussAssId);
```

here I want to use groupingBy condition for month,day,hour,deviceType and get count of userId.

similer to:

```
select month,day,hour,device_type,PPC_TYPE,click_source,count(user_id) from ne_tracking_info group by month,day,hour,device_type;
```

I used following code for grouping but not understanding how to sort.

```
Map<Integer,Map<String,Map<Integer,Map<String,List<PostgreSQLModel>>>>> device=sqlModelList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(p->p.getMonth(),Collectors.groupingBy(p->p.getDay(),Collectors.groupingBy(p->p.getHour(),Collectors.groupingBy(p->p.getPrimaryKeys().getDeviceType())))));
```

the output should be like below:

[image: output exampe]

Comment: `Map<Integer,Map<String,Map<Integer,Map<String,List<PostgreSQLModel>>>>>` If your types ever look like this, you are doing something seriously wrong.

Comment: @Michael I want to use groupingBy for multiple fields how can i  achive that?

Comment: to sort use `list.stream().sorted(Comparator)`

Comment: To use groupingBy for multiple fields, have separate Maps: one simple map for each grouped field. It doesn't have to be all in one big multi-level map.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException Could you please give me an example?

Comment: @stackuser just for simplicity and an idea -  group the fields month, day, hour into a single object say `ModelDate`, then just group by `ModelDate` and perform `Collectors.counting` as downstream.

Comment: Allow me to suggest you use the built-in enums `Month` and `DayOfWeek` rather than an `int` and a string.

Comment: `Map<List<Object>,Long> device=sqlModelList.stream() .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(p -> Arrays.asList(p.getMonth(), p.getDay(), p.getHour(), p.getPrimaryKeys() .getDeviceType()), Collectors.counting()));`, but it’s better to replace `List<Object>` by a dedicated key type having the desired properties (and appropriate `hashCode`/`equals` implementations). Then, stream over the map to convert the entries into a result record type (holding the key properties and the count), sort them and collect into a `List`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to group the data first and sort them afterwards:

```
List<GroupModelClass> devices = sqlModelList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(GroupModelClass::new, Collectors.counting()))
        .entrySet().stream()
        .map(e -> e.getKey().setCount(e.getValue()))
        .sorted(Comparator.comparingLong(GroupModelClass::getCount).reversed())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

After the first collect (`grouping`) the count value is added to the objects, the objects are sorted and collected to a list.

This uses a custom object to represent the grouped data:

```
public static class GroupModelClass {
    private int month;
    private String day;
    private int hour;
    private String deviceType;
    private long count;

    public GroupModelClass(ModelClass model) {
        this.month = model.getMonth();
        this.day = model.getDay();
        this.hour = model.getHour();
        this.deviceType = model.getDeviceType();
    }

    public GroupModelClass setCount(long count) {
        this.count = count;
        return this;
    }

    // getter

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        GroupModelClass that = (GroupModelClass) o;
        return month == that.month &&
                hour == that.hour &&
                count == that.count &&
                Objects.equals(day, that.day) &&
                Objects.equals(deviceType, that.deviceType);
    }
}
```

The result will be a list of `groupModels` sorted descending by count.